# add a macro button to a cell

Tags: vba, excel

My spreadsheet will be used by people who don't have any/little excel experience, so I have created macros for them to make it easier.

The issue I now face, if they add data into a new row, I want a new macro button to be created. The macro button would be a copy of the one above it.

Basically, in column E are the buttons, the macro associated opens a hidden page and filters on the word found in column D (corresponding row)

What I think i need, is when the other macro that returns them to the original page looks in column D and makes sure there is a button in column E and if not copies the macro button in the cell above and paste it in to E.

```
    'find content of the cell the button is on
    Dim b As Object, RowNumber As Integer
    Set b = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller)
    With b.TopLeftCell
        RowNumber = .Row
    End With

    protocolName = Range("D" & RowNumber).Value

'swap sheets and hide the other
    Sheets("Protocols").Visible = True
    Sheets("Orderables with Protocols").Visible = False
    Sheets("Protocols").Select


     ActiveSheet.Range("B:B").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=protocolName

    Range("A1").Select
```

Can anyone help please

Comment: set the `.Left` and `.Top` property of the button for where you want it

Comment: I think i may have wrote it wrong... what i need ie.. if there is text in cell D107, then the VBA to check if E107 has a macro button and if not create one in E107 (by copy and pasting the one from E106)... obviously this needs to be dynamic and not static cell

Comment: It's generally a bad design choice to put a button on each roe. too many buttons! Some would use the same button and move it with the selection using the `Selection_Change` event. Personally I would opt for the mouse double-click action instead of buttons.